# Can't overload apply method in Scala Implicit class

Tags: scala, apply, implicit

I am writing a `retry` function with `async` and `await`

```
  def awaitRetry[T](times: Int)(block: => Future[T]): Future[T] = async {
    var i = 0
    var result: Try[T] = Failure(new RuntimeException("failure"))

    while (result.isFailure && i < times) {
      result = await { Try(block) } // can't compile
      i += 1
    }

    result.get
  }
```

The Scala compiler reports an error. Since `Try` doesn't have apply methods takes `Future[T]`. So I solved it using **implicit classes**

```
  implicit class TryCompanionOps(val t: Try.type) extends AnyVal {
    // can't use `apply`!
    def convertTriedFuture[T](f: => Future[T]): Future[Try[T]] = 
      f.map(value => Try(value))
  }  

  // now we can convert Future[T] into Future[Try[T]] e.g,
  await { Try.convertTriedFuture(block) }
```

My question is,
Why can't I use the name `apply` instead of `convertTriedFuture`? It seems that the scala compiler doesn't allow **overload** only about `apply` methods in **implicit classes**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala starts to look for implicit conversions, only when it can't find an existing method with the required signature. But in `Try` companion object there is already a suitable method: `def apply[T](r: ⇒ T): Try[T]`, so Scala infers `T` in `apply` as `Future[Something]` and doesn't check for implicit conversions.

Also, this implementation won't work:

```
def convertTriedFuture[T](f: => Future[T]): Future[Try[T]] = 
  f.map(value => Try(value))
```

If the `Future` is failed, `map`'s function isn't called, and the Exception is thrown from `await`, and `async` immediately results in a failed `Future`. So with this implementation the function doesn't actually retry.

You need something like:

```
def convertTriedFuture[T](f: => Future[T]): Future[Try[T]] =
  f.map(Success.apply).recover { case e => Failure(e) }
```

Also, I think, it might be cleaner to define this recovery method on Futures:

```
implicit class FutureAdditionalOps[T](f: Future[T]) {
  def recoverError: Future[Try[T]] =
    f.map(Success.apply).recover { case e => Failure(e) }
}
```

And then you can have

```
result = await { block.recoverError }
```

Comment: Comment on potential performance problem is very helpful. Thanks Kolmar.